# Order by foreign key value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables: projects and demands. Every demand belongs to one project. I want to be able to order the demands by the project's name.

I tried Demand.joins(:project).order(:name) but I have this error:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: demands.name: SELECT "demands".* FROM "demands" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."id" = "demands"."project_id"  ORDER BY "demands"."name" ASC`

Here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150721144552) do
 create_table "demands", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.integer  "project_id"
  t.integer  "skill_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
 end

 add_index "demands", ["project_id"], name: "index_demands_on_project_id"

 create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "image"
  t.string   "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
 end
end
```

Comment: for a demand there is only one project. why you want order on just one project object.?

Comment: I want to order the demands according the alphabetical name of their project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
@demand.joins(:project).order("projects.name")
```

the argument to `order` is a db field.  if there's more than one table involved (as there is in a join) you should always specify the table.  When you don't specify it you run the risk of the rails-generated sql looking for that field in the wrong table, as is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it will always try to perform it on the first table i.e demands in this case. Whenever there are more then one table included and you want to perform query on other table then the first one you should reference it with table name.
In this example it would be:

```
@demand.joins(:project).order("projects.name")
```

Just for example if you want a condition on second table

```
@demand.joins(:project).where("projects.name = ?","My Project")
```